# php file that returns a string json encode didnt work

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have an php file that gives me the response i need as a string, i need it to be an array encoded in json, im not that good with php, can any one help ? 
this is how it works fine as a string
 - `printf("user: \"%s\" \"%s\" email: \"%s\" \n", $row['firstname'], $row['lastname'],$row['email']);`

But i need it as an array in json that is how i tried to do it
-`array_push($mynewArray,array("firstname \%s"=>$row['firstname'],"lastname \%s"=>$row['lastname'],"email \%s"=>$row['email']));
echo json_encode($mynewArray);`

[this is the screen shot that shows how i tried to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ojW.png)

Comment: Using array keys of the form `firstname \%s` probably doesn’t make the most sense ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try like this assuming the recordset is generated correctly and available in the var `$row`

```
$mynewArray=array();
foreach($result as $row){
    $mynewArray[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($mynewArray);


Or

$mynewArray=array();
foreach( $result as $row ){
    $mynewArray[]=array(
        'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
        'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
        'email'=>$row['email'],
    );
}
echo json_encode($mynewArray);
```

Comment: you saved me thannks you RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after:

```
<?php
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
                ->build();
$keyspace = 'msata';
$session = $cluster->connect($keyspace);

$result = $session->execute(new Cassandra\SimpleStatement
            ("SELECT * FROM msata.users")
          );

// Create the variable array here so it's used correctly in the loop
$mynewArray = array();

foreach( $result as $row ){

    // Create an array for each individual user
    $user_array = array( 'firstname' => $row['firstname'], 'lastname' => $row['lastname'], 'email' => $row['lastname'] );

    // Add the array to the main array
    $mynewArray = array_push( $mynewArray, $user_array );

}

echo json_encode( $mynewArray );
```